# Multiple outputs from NDsolve with incremental changes in initial condition?

Tags: differential-equations

```
b = 3.1 
eqnx1[t_] = ....
eqnx2[t_] = ....
...
x10 = b/2;
y10 = 0;
...

gsln = NDSolve[{eqnx1[t], eqny1[t], eqnz1[t], eqnx2[t], eqny2[t], 
   eqnz2[t], x1[0] == x10, y1[0] == y10, z1[0] == z10, 
   Derivative[1][x1][0] == vx10, Derivative[1][y1][0] == vy10, 
   Derivative[1][z1][0] == vz10, x2[0] == x20, y2[0] == y20, 
   z2[0] == z20, x2'[0] == vx20, y2'[0] == vy20, z2'[0] == vz20, 
   WhenEvent[Abs[z1[t] - z2[t]] > b*\[CapitalStigma], end = t;
...
\[CapitalDelta]d = Sqrt[(x1sln[end] - x10)^2 + (y1sln[end] - y10)^2];
```

Is there a way to code so that I can get different outputs for Delta for different values of the initial condition variable b? I would like b to increase in increments of .1 and run through the NDSolve to get a value for Delta.

Comment: You could use Manipulate and make `b` a control variable which you can change using a slider. Each time you change `b` you run the `NDSolve` again and  compute the new delta.

Comment: Is there a way to get a list of generated outputs for the new delta? rather than moving a slider to record each value?

Comment: `Is there a way to get a list of generated outputs` sure. You could store them in a list. If you do not know the size of the list needed, you can make it grow as needed as the program run.  `list={};
AppendTo[list,1]; AppendTo[list,2]` etc...

Comment: "incremental changes in initial condition" - sounds like a job for `ParametricNDSolve[]`.